# How to match the words in one document with several other documents and get the count in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a document with words as
spring
season
bank

Now I want to check if these words for present in several documents, lets say 10 documents. Input and the list of documents should be user defined. can anyone suggest me how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

what about `grep`?

```
grep -REic 'spring|season|bank' file1.txt file2.txt ...
```

check out `man grep` for more options.